# Simple PL/SQL code to throw NO_DATA_FOUND exception

Tags: oracle, plsql

In a recent interview I was asked to write a simple PL/SQL code to throw NO_DATA_FOUND exception without actually raising it from the code. I am wondering what could be a simple pl/sql snippet to do so. Probably using dual?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many ways, but as you suggested, you can use `DUAL`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE NODATAFOUND
AS
   nowt VARCHAR(10);
BEGIN
   SELECT * INTO nowt FROM DUAL WHERE 1=0;
END;
/
```

It'll produce a `ORA-01403: no data found` when `execute`d.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an existing table from project structure with an impossible where clause.
For example a negative number on PK when PK i defined as positive, etc.

Strange question in an interview....I never got that kind.

Comment: The idea behind the question was to use simplistic code without assuming any tables or raising this exception I think. But yes this would obviously work.

Answer (score 0):

How about

raise no_data_found;